# .NET Parameter vs DbParameter classes

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, parameters

Does anyone have a clear explanation for how these two classes are related and what their differences are?  I know that `Parameter` is used for data-source web controls, whereas `DbParameter` (or rather, a class derived from it) is used in `DbCommand` functions such as `ExecuteNonQuery()`; but why are there two different classes that seem to accomplish the same thing?